# Stack trace with line numbers when running cargo run

Tags: rust, stack-trace, rust-cargo

Doing `RUST_BACKTRACE=1 cargo run` gives a stack trace when an error occurs as shown below. Is there any way to get the file & line number instead of the hex address?

```
thread '<main>' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Parsing: invalid encoding byte', /Users/rustbuild/src/rust-buildbot/slave/stable-dist-rustc-mac/build/src/libcore/result.rs:729
stack backtrace:
   1:        0x104c9403f - sys::backtrace::write::h7807ec07859fb503t1r
   2:        0x104c980e4 - panicking::on_panic::ha0ed2b9b562a7f9ctZv
   3:        0x104c7c4d5 - rt::unwind::begin_unwind_inner::hbfb8d99cb52be7a1cHv
   4:        0x104c7cd66 - rt::unwind::begin_unwind_fmt::hac7eda7c3f3b8498QFv
   5:        0x104c979bc - rust_begin_unwind
   6:        0x104cb75f5 - panicking::panic_fmt::h051633da0da2e362wwy
   7:        0x104be0877 - result::Result<T, E>::unwrap::h15040486031244389916
   8:        0x104bdc6f1 - main::h393644ca2d1fdb82uLa
   9:        0x104c99e18 - rust_try_inner
  10:        0x104c99e05 - rust_try
  11:        0x104c988e8 - rt::lang_start::h5324dae87dacdac8YTv
  12:        0x104be500e - main
An unknown error occurred
```

Comment: Which platform are you on? I thought that Linux did have file names and line numbers.

Comment: @Shepmaster: only for debug builds, not for release builds.

Comment: @Shepmaster I using OS X 10.10

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: This looks like your comment could be turned into an answer; is the issue a lack of debugging symbols (a `-g` flag could help?) or is it that even if debugging symbols were present they would be ignored anyway?

Comment: @BilalHussain: In Release modes, file names and line numbers can be greatly mangled by the various optimizations. after all, you may notice that the stack trace is incomplete (missing intermediate functions) for example, etc... In general, you have to learn to live with it, and if the information is insufficient, then find a way to reproduce the issue and try it in Debug.

Answer (score 10):

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/22839) merged into main rust repo which adds file names and line numbers to backtrace. As far as I can see it was a part of rust 1.0.0 stable release.

You have to enable backtraces and build executable using [cargo profile](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#the-profile-sections) which includes debug symbols into executable (with `debug = true` option in cargo manifest). AFAIK `cargo run` is using debug profile by default now.

Here is example trace output with file names and line numbers:

```
[user@salikhov ~/workspace/mqtt-rust $ RUST_BACKTRACE=1 cargo run
   Compiling mqtt v0.1.0 (file:///home/user/workspace/mqtt-rust)

     Running `target/debug/mqtt`
thread '<main>' panicked at 'I want line numbers!', src/proto/client.rs:33
stack backtrace:
   1:     0x7ff049fa47d9 - sys::backtrace::tracing::imp::write::he18882fa84e6b00ePnt
   2:     0x7ff049fa39b8 - panicking::on_panic::h495226a97f084523enx
   3:     0x7ff049f9dcce - sys_common::unwind::begin_unwind_inner::h7a4ee06c0d57e26affs
   4:     0x7ff049f95f47 - sys_common::unwind::begin_unwind::h13029855766851973181
                        at ../src/libstd/sys/common/unwind/mod.rs:232
   5:     0x7ff049f95e8a - proto::client::MqttConnection::connect::h633d3d42c15a3dedgYa
                        at /home/user/workspace/mqtt-rust/<std macros>:3
   6:     0x7ff049f80416 - main::h1d77c75265710f92gaa
                        at src/main.rs:5
   7:     0x7ff049fa6084 - sys_common::unwind::try::try_fn::h4848098439110500489
   8:     0x7ff049fa3098 - __rust_try
   9:     0x7ff049fa5cf8 - rt::lang_start::hcf64c98c1a7c0031Zkx
  10:     0x7ff049f834f6 - main
  11:     0x7ff049170ec4 - __libc_start_main
  12:     0x7ff049f802a8 - <unknown>
  13:                0x0 - <unknown>
An unknown error occurred
```

Unfortunately, this is broken on some platforms like MacOS X. There is open [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24346) about this in rust github issue tracker.

Comment: @Shepmaster pull request states that it works on any non-Android POSIX OS - don't know if it's including MacOS X

Comment: I can state that as of Rust 1.5, backtraces do not have line numbers on OS X. I don't see them ^_^

Comment: On OS X 10.11  using Rust 1.5, I still don't see the line numbers

Comment: And a year and a half later I still don't see the line numbers. (Rust 1.19, OSX 10.12). #OneDay

Answer (score 1):

If you go into the deps subdirectory and run the program from there you will now get line numbers in OSX.

This is due to this open issue which hopefully will be fixed soon:
https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/4490